# App to app voice call like Viber & Line in android

Tags: android, sip, voip

Recently I am working on an application in which I have to implement application to application **voice call and instant messaging** like Viber and Line.

I did some R&D and got two methods to implement voice call.

1. **SIP**

   a. [android.net.sip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html)

   b. [SIP API Classes and Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html#classes)
2. **VoIP**

But I am confused how to use it. How to Setup SIP server for my app on my own server and on what basis I will call my friends like I have 4 friends  in my app contacts.I have to call second one, then what parameter should I pass to call him/her using SIP.

Comment: [VOIP Server Installation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-KVjzOutTk) /// [Free VOIP Application Doubango-IMSDroid](https://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/) /// [SiPServer cloud-voip-step-by-step](http://minisipserver.com/docs/setup-cloud-voip-step-by-step/index.html)

Comment: @SilentKiller  i have a google server dude,not a IIS7.

Comment: you wanna use VOIP or SIP.?

Comment: SIP is native api so finally i decide to use SIP.

Comment: have you checked [CSipSample](https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) App.?

Comment: yeah....it crashes. and i don't want to use any lib.becuse i am working on a product.i'll do whole code by my own.

Comment: Its same thing what you need.. its open source so you can use its code. it is also using SIP API Classes and Interface.

Comment: yeahh.. i knew that.but still,and right now my  requirement is to write a server for my app first.client i will write later. so provide me some useful links for server.

Comment: i want to integrate SIP protocol on my server like viber. i purchased server from google.

Comment: [You didn't see this.](https://www.sipwise.com/news/technical/byov-skype-replacement/) And If it is related to installing SIP or VOIP server, move your question [here](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: hey downvoters,please dont close this questions.this not that much broad you are thinking.i just want to know a basic server integration.

Comment: I think the steps outlining how to use the native client will help you continue with your application. 

I found the following link to help you out: 
https://github.com/Metaswitch/clearwater-docs/wiki/Configuring-the-native-Android-SIP-client

Answer (score -1):

The Simplest way I can see to create an application like this would to have a backend database with a user login system, the create a table to hold IP addresses corresponding to the users in the database. This way you could have a function to update the devices IP upon logging in or periodically while online (currently logged in). This would allow a second device using the application to find the other devices current IP and create a VoIP connection between the two.

Things you would need to know:
how to create a VoIP connection.
how to query a database use mySQL or JSON parsing.
how to set up a small database on a webserver.

Your question is far to broad to go into detail as those details may not be what you are looking for specifically and thus not worth explaining, but I hope this helps you to look in the right direction.